# Cannot pass Select2 parms into UI-select2

Tags: angularjs-select2, ui-select2

I'm trying to use the ui-select2 Angular directive, and the github repo states:

> All the select2 options can be passed through the directive. You can read more about the supported list of options and what they do on the Select2 Documentation Page

I have the directive working, but am unable to pass in simple options (ie: they are ignored).
For example:

**html**

```
<form>
   <input type='hidden' ui-select2='selectGenes' ng-model='selectedGene' , ng-required="true">
</form>
```

**js**

```
$scope.selectGenes = {
  minimumInputLength: 2,
 'ajax': {
   url: "/api/genes.json",
   dataType: 'json',
   data: function(term, page) {
     return { q: term }; 
   },
   results: function(data, page) {
       var index;
       for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index){
           data[index].text = data[index].name2;
       };
     return { results: data };
   }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. The Select2 parms need to be quoted.

```
$scope.selectGenes = {
  'minimumInputLength': 2,
  'placeholder': 'Enter Gene',
```